# Hide First Element Only, Exclude Nested Elements WITHOUT class or IDs

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list on my webpage.

```
Home      News      About
           - Weather
           - Sports
           - Local Events
```

I'd like to simply hide *only* the `Home` list item with CSS, here's what I have;

```
ul li:first-child { display: none; }
```

Clearly this will hide every single first `li` of every `ul`, even the nested elements. And here's the kicker, I ***cannot*** give it a class or ID. That being said, how can I target `Home` only via CSS?

Comment: Give it a class or id - that's what they are for.

Comment: I failed to mention, I cannot give it a class or ID. Believe it or not.

Comment: Where does your unordered list (that contains Home) lie in your HTML? If you have no way of narrowing down even the top-level list, any generic styling we supply is going to hide the first item of any other top-level list on the page.

Comment: Then you would have to select based on some other "uniqueness". Does the list have an ancestor that has a unique class or an ID? Or is it perhaps in a `<header>` or some other element that isn't repeated in the document? Show us some HTML.

Comment: Unless you can select the `ul` by an additional unique specific selector... **You can't**.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, you can. And I did.

Comment: @KuraiBankusu You may get an unpleasant surprise when you try to include another nested list on your page...ie. https://jsfiddle.net/ve0yn4gr/ (unless this is the only list with a nested list you plan to have on your page, in which case that would've been helpful to share). Also, this still seems to hide the first item of the nested list? Just with even more problematic side-effects...

Comment: This is the only UL going on my page @Serlite

Comment: @KuraiBankusu That's a really important detail, as it removes the need to identify the top-level list. Please be sure to include details like those in future questions, or readers may again be faced with insufficient information to assist you. (We don't want the answer section to turn into a guessing game.)

Comment: @Serlite Sure! will do

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
  <li> ola1</li>
  <li> ola2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li> xau1</li>
  <li> xau2</li>
</ul>




ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Just14/pen/KaNvVN

Comment: This is too brittle. There could be any number of lists in a document.

Comment: The answer above is correct, it's hidding the first list and subsequently the first element. If you need to be more specific then i would advise for you to show some markup so we can force on the css parent nesting with, for example, the > operator.

Comment: It also suffers from this problem - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dNOzWr Any submenu will **also** be the `first-of-type` and it's first child will be hidden.

Comment: something like this? 

http://codepen.io/pedromrb/pen/GrNvyg

only 2 levels deep? you can control the which li element you wanna target, for dynamic solutions i would advise sass loops or something in that order.

Answer (score 2):

You can access to the first **li** of the first **ul**

```
ul:first-child li:first-child { display: none; }
```

Comment: This is too brittle. There could be any number of lists in a document.